# Teradata Connection with Microsoft Excel Macro

Tags: vb.net, excel, odbc, teradata

I am getting problem while trying to run Marcos in Microsoft Excel for Teradata Connection. My code for Connecting Teradata through marcos

```
Dim hostName As String: hostName = "locahost"
Dim dbName As String: dbName = "STG_CNV"
Dim username As String: username = "username"
Dim password As String: password = "password"
Dim Row As Integer: Row = 1

Dim Query As String, lastColumn As Integer, lastRow As Long

'Connect to database
Conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
          "DBCName=" & hostName & ";" & _
          "Database=" & dbName & ";" & _
          "Uid=" & username & ";" & _
          "Pwd=" & password & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""EXTENDLOBSUPPORT=Yes"""
          '"Extended Properties=""USENATIVELOBSUPPORT=Yes"""
```

I am Error in as

```
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Drive] Major Status=0x04bd Minor Status=0xe1000095-[terasso] Cannot load TDGSS library.
```

As I know this is problem with ODBC drive. But my teradata client is running wiht ODBC drive but in Microsoft Excel, its not. How can we solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Teradata ODBC Client requires two additional libraries to be installed on the client, the Shared ICU Libraries and GSS Library. They generally have to be selected separately to be installed as part of the Teradata Client or Tools and Utilities installation package.

Sometimes if you are upgrading to a newer version of the driver and don't install them correctly it can cause problems when you install the newer release of the client. If that happens you typically have to uninstall everything relating to the Teradata client and start over.

Have you recently installed or upgraded the ODBC Driver?